# Error on Downloading From using Asp.net web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the code below for downloading with the web API in ASP.NET.
When I'm trying to click the download button, it calls the API.
After executing the "DownloadFile"-function, the download dialog box isn't coming .

[HttpGet]

```
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(string DownloadFilePath)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(DownloadFilePath);

        // check if parameter is valid
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DownloadFilePath))
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        // check if file exists on the server
        else if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
        else
        {// serve the file to the client
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = DownloadFilePath;
        }

        return result;




    }
```

I didn't get any exception from the code above, but the dialog box for downloading the file isn't coming.

Comment: try to add try-catch in your method, and see if there might be an error.

Comment: not getting any exception in try catch

Comment: " rob waminal " is need any changes in web config?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, I am using and it works great. I hope it will give you an idea

```
....
var fileBytes = Helper.GetFileBytes(filePath);//convert file to bytes
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
                    resp.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = filerequest.FileName };
                    resp.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");               
                    return resp;
```

And, here is the code for GetFileBytes method,

```
public static byte[] GetFileBytes(string filePath)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                return File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
            }
            return null;           
        }
```